# Best way to type hint a union of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I'm writing a function that I want to be able to take either a pandas `DataFrame` (`pd.DataFrame`) or a pandas-on-spark `DataFrame` (`ps.DataFrame`).

I here is my function:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import pandas as pd
from typing import TypeVar

ADataFrame = TypeVar("ADataFrame", pd.DataFrame, ps.DataFrame)


def format_table(
    df: ADataFrame
) -> ADataFrame:
    renamed = df.loc[
        :, ["ID", "code"]
    ].rename(
        columns={
            "ID": "new_id",
            "code": "new_code"
        }
    )
    return renamed
```

When I run mypy I get `error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[Series[Any], DataFrame[Any], None]", expected "DataFrame[Any]")`.

My guess is that each of `pd.DataFrame.rename` and `ps.DataFrame.rename` have different return types, which causes these kind of issues (this is just one of them, I get similar issues when I try to merge the DataFrames.

Looking for any suggestions on the best way to type hint these functions.

Comment: Type hinting to make `mypy` happy is always a good thing. But as an alternative, you might consider defining a new `class` that flexibly supports both kinds of dataframe. Then type hinting becomes very simple.

Comment: @J_H can you give me a short example of what you mean?

Comment: The problem is that `rename` can return `None`, a possibility that `format_table` ignores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rename`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L5451-L5579) can return `None`:

> ```
>  def rename(
>         self,
>         mapper: Renamer | None = None,
>         *,
>         index: Renamer | None = None,
>         columns: Renamer | None = None,
>         axis: Axis | None = None,
>         copy: bool | None = None,
>         inplace: bool = False,
>         level: Level = None,
>         errors: IgnoreRaise = "ignore",
>     ) -> DataFrame | None:
>         ...
> ```

Your function ignores that possibility. (The error message is expanding `Union[Union[Series[Any], DataFrame[Any]], None]` to `Union[Series[Any], DataFrame[Any], None]`.)

Just update your return type to accomodate it. Nothing in the body of the function needs to change.

```
def format_table(
    df: ADataFrame
) -> ADataFrame | None:
    ...
```

This is exactly the kind of bug that static typing helps prevent at runtime.

If you want to *assert* that your `rename` cannot fail (are you sure?), you can use `cast` to tell the type checker it's OK.

```
def format_table(
    df: ADataFrame
) -> ADataFrame:
    ...
    return cast(ADataFrame, renamed)
```

or you can catch the error at runtime. If `return` executes, type narrowing is used to automatically perform the same cast.

```
def format_table(
    df: ADataFrame
) -> ADataFrame:
    ...
    if renamed is None:
        raise ValueError("data frame could not be formatted")

    return renamed
```

Answer (score 0):

> can you give me a short example of what you mean?

This flexible frame class supports both kinds of dataframe.
And then type hinting becomes very simple.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.context as pc
import pyspark.pandas as sp


class Delegator:
    def _get_obj(self):
        # We're either delegating to pandas or to spark.
        return self.pd if self.pd is not None else self.sp

    def __getattr__(self, called_method):
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return getattr(self._get_obj(), called_method)(*args, **kwargs)

        return _wrapper

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._get_obj()[item]


class FlexFrame(Delegator):
    def __init__(self, arg, **kwargs):
        rec = arg.to_records(index=False)
        self.pd = self.sp = None
        if isinstance(arg, pd.DataFrame):
            self.pd = pd.DataFrame(rec, **kwargs)
        elif isinstance(arg, sp.DataFrame):
            self.sp = sp.DataFrame(rec, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Unexpected type: {type(arg)}")


def format_table(df: FlexFrame) -> FlexFrame:
    assert isinstance(df, FlexFrame)

    df = df.copy()[["id", "code"]]
    return df.rename(columns={"id": "new_id", "code": "new_code"})


def get_pandas_example() -> FlexFrame:
    return FlexFrame(pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], "code": ["a", "b", "c"]}))


def get_pyspark_example() -> FlexFrame:
    return FlexFrame(sp.DataFrame({"id": [4, 5, 6], "code": ["d", "e", "f"]}))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pc.SparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR")

    print(format_table(get_pandas_example()))
    print(format_table(get_pyspark_example()))
```